# std::copy, std::copy_backward and overlapping ranges

Tags: c++, c++11, stdcopy

My references are to [std::copy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) and [std::copy_backward](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_backward).

> template< class InputIt, class OutputIt > OutputIt copy( InputIt
>   first, InputIt last, OutputIt d_first );
>
> Copies all elements in the range [first, last) starting from first and
>   proceeding to last - 1. The behavior is undefined if d_first is within
>   the range [first, last). In this case, std::copy_backward may be used
>   instead.
>
> template< class BidirIt1, class BidirIt2 > BidirIt2 copy_backward(
>   BidirIt1 first, BidirIt1 last, BidirIt2 d_last )
>
> Copies the elements from the range, defined by [first, last), to
>   another range ending at d_last. The elements are copied in reverse
>   order (the last element is copied first), but their relative order is
>   preserved.
>
> The behavior is undefined if d_last is within (first, last]. std::copy
>   must be used instead of std::copy_backward in that case.
>
> When copying overlapping ranges, std::copy is appropriate when copying
>   to the left (beginning of the destination range is outside the source
>   range) while std::copy_backward is appropriate when copying to the
>   right (end of the destination range is outside the source range).

From the above description, I gather the following inference:

Both copy and copy_backward end up copying the same source range [first, last) to the destination range, albeit in the case of the former the copying occurs from first to last - 1, whereas in the case of the latter the copying occurs from last -1 to first. In both cases, relative order of elements in the source range is preserved in the resulting destination range.

However, what is the technical reason behind the following two stipulations:

1) In the case of copy, undefined behavior results (implying unsuccessful copying of the source range to the destination range and possibly system fault) if d_first is within the range [first, last).

2) In the case of copy_backward, undefined behavior results (implying unsuccessful copying of the source range to the destination range and possibly system fault) if d_last is within the range (first, last].

I am assuming that the suggestion to replace copy with copy_backward to avert the above undefined behavior scenario, would become evident to me once I understand the implication of the above two statements.

Likewise, I am also assuming that the mention about the appropriateness of copy when copying to the left (which notion is not clear to me), and copy_backward when copying to the right (which notion is not clear to me either), would begin to make sense once I comprehend the above distinction between copy and copy_backward.

Look forward to your helpful thoughts as always.

## Addendum

As a follow-up, I wrote the following test code to verify the behavior of both copy and copy_backward, for identical operation.

```
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

using std::array;
using std::copy;
using std::copy_backward;
using std::size_t;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main (void)
{
    const size_t sz = 4;

    array<int,sz>a1 = {0,1,2,3};
    array<int,sz>a2 = {0,1,2,3};

    cout << "Array1 before copy" << endl;
    cout << "==================" << endl;

    for(auto&& i : a1) //the type of i is int&
    {
        cout << i << endl;
    }

    copy(a1.begin(),a1.begin()+3,a1.begin()+1);

    cout << "Array1 after copy" << endl;
    cout << "=================" << endl;

    for(auto&& i : a1) //the type of i is int&
    {
        cout << i << endl;
    }

    cout << "Array2 before copy backward" << endl;
    cout << "===========================" << endl;

    for(auto&& i : a2) //the type of i is int&
    {
        cout << i << endl;
    }

    copy_backward(a2.begin(),a2.begin()+3,a2.begin()+1);

    cout << "Array2 after copy backward" << endl;
    cout << "==========================" << endl;

    for(auto&& i : a2) //the type of i is int&
    {
        cout << i << endl;
    }


    return (0);
}
```

The following is the program output:

```
Array1 before copy
==================
0
1
2
3
Array1 after copy
=================
0
0
1
2
Array2 before copy backward
===========================
0
1
2
3
Array2 after copy backward
==========================
2
1
2
3
```

Evidently, copy produces the expected result, whereas copy_backward doesn't, even though d_first is within the range [first, last). Additionally, d_last is within the range (first, last] as well, which should result in undefined behavior in the case of copy_backward as per the documentation.

So in effect, the program output is in accordance with the documentation in the case of copy_backward, whereas it is not in the case of copy.

It is worth noting again that in both cases, d_first and d_last do satisfy the condition which should result in undefined behavior for both copy and copy_backward respectively, as per documentation. However, the undefined behavior is observed only in the case of copy_backward.

Comment: I'm sorry, what is your question?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit please refer to my edit above

Comment: That didn't really clarify anything. Please ask a specific question.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I have reworded the question and hopefully it is more evident now.

Comment: Simply take a moment to think about what `copy` might physically do if you’re attempting to sequentially copy the first and second slots of an array to the second and third slots of that array.

Comment: The last parameter for copy_backward is destination.end() (which is a bit surprising, but makes sense since the copying 'starts' there) What is a bit shocking, however, is that no one pointed to that mistake in your code. I guess 'one' was done with your question before you could post the update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing deep going on here. Just do an algorithm run-through with sample data using a naive approach: copy each element in order.

Suppose you have the four-element array `int a[4] = {0, 1, 2, 3}` and you want to copy the first three elements to the last three. Ideally, you would end up with `{0, 0, 1, 2}`. How would this (not) work with `std::copy(a, a+3, a+1)`?

**Step 1:** Copy the first element `a[1] = a[0];` The array is now `{0, 0, 2, 3}`.

**Step 2:** Copy the second element `a[2] = a[1];` The array is now `{0, 0, 0, 3}`.

**Step 3:** Copy the third element `a[3] = a[2];` The array is now `{0, 0, 0, 0}`.

The result is wrong because you overwrote some of your source data (`a[1]` and `a[2]`) before reading those values. Copying in reverse would work because in reverse order, you would read values before overwriting them.

Since the result is wrong with one reasonable approach, the standard declared the behavior "undefined". Compilers wishing to take the naive approach may, and they do not have to account for this case. It is OK to be wrong in this case. Compilers that take a different approach might produce different results, maybe even the "correct" results. That is also OK. Whatever is easiest for the compiler is fine by the standard.

---

In light of the question's addendum: please note that this is [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior). That does not mean the behavior is defined to be contrary to the programmer's intent. Rather, it means that the behavior is *not defined* by the C++ standard. It is up to each compiler to decide what happens. The result of `std::copy(a, a+3, a+1)` could be anything. You might get the naive result of `{0, 0, 0, 0}`. However, you might instead get the intended result of `{0, 0, 1, 2}`. Other results are also possible. You cannot conclude that there is no undefined behavior simply because you were lucky enough to get the behavior you intended. *Sometimes undefined behavior gives correct results.* (That's one reason that tracking down bugs related to undefined behavior can be so difficult.)

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that, in general, copying part of a range to another part of the same range, might require additional (if only temporary) storage, to handle overlaps when copying in sequence from left to right, or from right to left in your second example.

As is common with C++, to avoid forcing implementations to take this extreme step, the standard just tells you not to do it by saying the results are undefined.

This forces you, in such situations, to be explicit by copying into a fresh piece of memory yourself.

It does so while not even requiring the compiler to put any effort into warning or telling you about this, which would also be seen as "too bossy" on the part of the standard.

But your assumption that undefined behaviour here results in a copy failure (or a system fault) is also wrong. I mean, that could well *be* the result (and JaMiT demonstrates very well how this could occur) but you must not fall into the trap of expecting any particular result from a program with undefined behaviour; that's the point of it. Indeed, some implementation may even go to the trouble of making overlapping range copies "work" (though I'm not aware of any that do).

Comment: The output that I get for my test code does not align with JaMiT's observation. Neither does it align with the documentation for copy.

Comment: @Vinod Read my answer again. You cannot expect any particular result.